# jammy -- unsupported version 0 of Verneed record - processes like VSCode exit and won't relaunch

Tags: snap

At random intervals -- processes like visual studio code just exit and I can't get them to relaunch. Errors below:

```
➜  src_crypto_trader git:(main) ✗ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

✗ uname -a
Linux lahaina 6.0.5-060005-generic #202210261142 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Oct 26 11:54:33 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


g_module_open() failed for /snap/code/111/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-bmp.so: /snap/code/111/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-bmp.so: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record

g_module_open() failed for /snap/code/111/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-icns.so: /snap/code/111/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-icns.so: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record

g_module_open() failed for /snap/code/111/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-ico.so: /snap/code/111/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-ico.so: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record

g_module_open() failed for /snap/code/111/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-jpeg.so: /snap/code/111/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-jpeg.so: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record
```

Comment: just going to say this: if you use kernel 6.0 you are NOT going to have things work proper or guaranteed to work proper - kernel 6.0 isn't optimized nor recommended yet for the Ubuntu cycles and there are likely to be a ton of bugs.

Answer (score 5):

That appears to be a [squashfs bug on v6 of the Linux kernel](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/unsupported-version-0-of-verneed-record-linux-6-0/32160?u=kyrofa). No snaps appear to work properly until v6.0.7, where the fix landed. Either roll back to a kernel prior to v6, or update until you're on at least v6.0.7.

Comment: any more specific suggestions on how to do this (roll back or update)? (I'm on Pop!OS, but might be able to extrapolate from an Ubuntu-specific answer ...)

Comment: If this was a pop-shipped update, I don't have easy solutions. You might try asking them to update to 6.0.7 or later for you, but given that [snaps on pop are broken for other reasons](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1881189), you might not get much traction.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I ended up solving the problem by installing both of the apps that had problems with this (zulip and Skype) from apt-get instead of snap -- that resolved the problem